# Derived class =operator taking and returning Base reference

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, operators

my co-worker and I ran into some old code that has us a bit confused. Essentially it boils down to this.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() = default;
    std::string m_test;
    
    Base& operator=(const Base& other)
    {
        const Derived *pThat = (Derived*)&other;
        m_test = "Woo";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Can the = operator ever get called? Obviously there is the flaw that if it did get called the cast would fail on anything other Base but so far we couldn't think of any situation where this could actually legally be called.

Comment: Why do you think it can't be called?

Comment: The cast would not fail, but result in [demons flying out of everyone's noses](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) (a subtle distinction).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Careful, `pThat` is not dereferenced.

Comment: @lorro that was my fault. I cut out a bunch of stuff for the simplicity of the example, it did indeed dereference the pointer at some point

Comment: `(Derived*)` is a completely unrestricted cast. It is the Word of God to the compiler, and the compiler will dutifully switch off its brains and make it happen no matter how bad an idea the result will be. You're usually better off with a compiler error because at least with the hard error you know you have a problem. Whenever you see one of these suckers in the code, do what you've just done: Stop and carefully examine. It might turn out not to be a mistake, but after decades of this practice I don't think I've regretted the time spent as much as I did the time NOT spent.

Comment: @CMcL Yes, suspected that :). In that case, the second part of my answer applies. You might still call it like `Derived d; d = (Base&)d;`.

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` when you need to check polymorphism like this because it will return a very identifiable (and almost always fatal if used) `nullptr`.

Comment: @MooingDuck the thought process was that the equals operator returning Base& wouldn't allow an assignment to Derived but lorro has proven me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `operator=` can be called with any `other` that is-a `Base` (and is-not-a `Derived`, as in that case the default implementation would be called; but it can be any class publicly descending from `Base` or `Base` itself). Since `pThat` is not dereferenced, it's a valid code. Note: regardless of being valid or not, it's *very* dangerous, as UB can occur when dereferenced.

If `pThat` were dereferenced (e.g. you wrote `pThat->m_whatever`), then the code is only valid if `other` is-a `Derived`, otherwise it's UB.

Live demo:
https://ideone.com/encyK5